# Sort column view in open/save panel

Tags: macos, finder

I can sort (without using sections) in list view just fine, by clicking the column header. But I can't find any way to do this in column view, as there's no equivalent to the View Options panel (the View menu varies depending on the app).

Note that the Arrange By button works differently, so it is not a substitute. It controls the sections of files, while Sort By controls the sorting *within* those sections.

I'm open to things like `defaults` commands, but I'd rather not install external software if I don't have to. (But if you have something that works, by all means put it here!)

Answer (score 1):

In the "Open" dialog there is an icon that pops up a menu that allows you to choose the sort order.

[image]

In the Finder you can either use the same pop up or right click and the context menu has "Arrange By".

Comment: "Note that the Arrange By button works differently, so it is not a substitute". @seaturtle rather wants something like ⌘+J and "Sort By" in Finder.